# Media Screen - center a button

Tags: css, button, media-queries, screen, center

How do you center a button on a media screen only?

At the moment I have

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px)  {
    .mobile-break1 {  text-align:center; }
}

<span class="mobile-break1"><button>Book Online</button></span>
```

It doesn't center the button on a media screen or otherwise. I feel like I'm obviously doing something wrong but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `<span>` is an inline element. You cannot centre the button, because the inline element only takes up as much width as necessary.

You have a couple of options:

1. Tell the browser to treat your span as a block element. You can do this by adding the following to your CSS `display:block`.
2. Change your `<span>` to a `<div>`. The `<div>` is a block element by default, and would take the whole width of the page.

The `<div>` would be the preferred option.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job since `div` is a block level element.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 600px)  {
    .mobile-break1 {
      text-align:center;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-break1">
  <button>Book Online</button>
</div>
```